# THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have 20 3D objects to be rendered separately on a single page. The problem is only around 13 objects are loaded the rest don't show up. I get this error THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost in console. My objects are relatively light, 1MB in average size. And they have a light texture maximum of 2 MB. I read this error is related to memory and RAM. But as I mentioned my files are not that heavy.

Do you guys think this has a solution? Maybe some recommendations.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the [`Help Center`](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [`The Tour`](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read some of the suggested articles, especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your question would specifically benefit from sharing code of what you're trying to do. Despite loading many objects, it sounds like there is something fundamental causing the loss of the GL context. I would guess it would fail even if you reduced it to a single object, but I could be wrong. The context can also be lost if you create too many contexts in the same page, or if there is some kind of failure in the context itself.